# How to pass value to skip and limit methods of MongoDB using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem passing value to the skip method of mongoDB. Below is the code that works, in this code I just pass number 10 into skip method.

```js
Post.find(finalQuery, (err, posts) => {
  if (err) {
    res.json({
      success: false,
      message: err
    });
  } else {
    if (!posts) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'No posts found.'
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        posts: posts
      });
    }
  }
}).sort({
  '_id': -1
}).skip(10).limit(10);
```

However I want to pass the value of skip as a variable, below is the code that doesn't work. I use http request to pass skip as a parameter. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```js
router.get('/getAllPosts/:skip', (req, res) => {
      let finalQuery = {}; //I have written correct query in actual code, skipped here for simplicity
      Post.find(finalQuery, (err, posts) => {
        if (err) {
          res.json({
            success: false,
            message: err
          });
        } else {
          if (!posts) {
            res.json({
              success: false,
              message: 'No posts found.'
            });
          } else {
            res.json({
              success: true,
              posts: posts
            });
          }
        }
      }).sort({
        '_id': -1
      }).skip(req.params.skip).limit(10);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`skip` takes a numerical parameter, not a string, so you need to convert:

```
.skip(Number(req.params.skip))
```